# Showing Multiple images one after the other with a delay in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Objective is to repeat the image after every 2 sec in cyclic order. I have created 2 functions, cycle and random, where in cycle, the image rotates too fast and is stuck, as if not repeating itself in cyclic order. Whereas in random function, it works fine, it keeps displaying random image every 2 second.

```
<script>
    var asgnimage = ["pic2.jpg","pic3.jpg", "pic1.jpg", "pic4.jpg"];
     function cycle(){
        for (i=0; i<asgnimage.length; i++){
            document.cb.src = asgnimage[i];
                    window.setTimeout("", 2000);
        }
        window.setTimeout ("cycle()",2000);
    }

    function rndm(){
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random(randomIndex) * 4)

            document.rm.src = asgnimage[randomIndex];

            setTimeout ("rndm()",2000);
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Re-check the correct usage of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really only need one `setTimeout` that calls the function over and over - no need for a `for/loop`. You can provide `setTimeout` with additional arguments that it can pass to the function when it is called - that's what I'll be using here: passing in a new index.

```js
const asgnimage = ["https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png", "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/aa4cc3/fff.png", "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/556476/fff.png", "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/563765/fff.png"];

// Default index to 0
function cycle(index = 0) {

  // Set your image
  document.querySelector('#cb').src = asgnimage[index];

  // If you reach the end of the array set index to zero
  // otherwise increment it
  let nextIndex = index === asgnimage.length - 1 ? 0 : ++index;

  // Call `cycle` again passing in the new `index`
  setTimeout(cycle, 2000, nextIndex);
}

cycle();
```

```html
<img id="cb" />
```